# Is WiFi RTT Ranging and WiFi Aware compatible when running concurrently in one Android app

Tags: wi-fi, connection-issues

I have a Google pixel 5 and I am currently developing both WiFi RTT ranging (ranging from access point, see [WiFi RTT](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifi-rtt)) and WiFi Aware (ranging from peer mobile, see [WiFi Aware](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifi-aware)) on it. Hardware-wise Google pixel 5 supports both functionalities, however I am not too sure if there will be any compatibility issue when both functions are running foreground. I am not sure if my concern is valid nor can I find any source of clarification.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the official Android Developer Doc of ***[RangingRequest.Builder](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/rtt/RangingRequest.Builder)*** class, there is a method called ***addWifiAwarePeer***, along with the ***addAccessPoints*** method. From which I assume these two functionalities can be implemented and run simultaneously.